# Insert html using JavaScript without using id?

Tags: javascript, html, inserthtml

I want to insert html using JavaScript with something like this : `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "example";` but i do not want to use id how can i do it by class name? I have tried `document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "example";` but it did not work either...or is there any why to insert html other than innerHTML using classes ..

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('class')`. It'll return an array of elements so you'll have to work with that.

Comment: @Phiter is correct.
getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements, you may use the index and target any element. If you think you have only one item or want to target first item use this snippet.

    document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML = "example";

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try by class `document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "TEXT/HTML"`

or

By tag `document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = "TEXT/HTML"`

You can see this methods here on documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: I have tried that but it does not seem to work.

Comment: So try this, 

`document.querySelector('.yourclassdemo').innerHTML = '<span>test</span>'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: this worked, thank you....

Answer (score -1):

You can use any css selector using the query selector function.
See here for more details:
[querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

If you want to do an action for every element that matches your css selector, use querySelectorAll instead, which returns a nore list.
[querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

Answer (score -2):

`document.getElementsByClassName("example");`

Comment: I have tried it but it does not work with innerHTML